# how does getElementsByClassName() work under the hood?

Tags: javascript

I've tended to just loop over elements selectively to find elements of a specific class, but I'm curious if using getElementsByClassName (for applicable browsers) will increase performance at all.

How does it actually WORK?

I could easily run a test to check performance obviously, but I'm really curious what's going on in there anyway.

Comment: Why did this instantly get a downvote?  Seems like a legitimate question to me.

Comment: Most likely because [a quick Google Search returns a lot about it](https://www.google.com/search?q=getelementsbyclassname+performance)? And most browsers (except IE) are open source so you can peek at how they implement that. Also, there's [sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/) which patches this for older browsers. You can check how they do it.

Comment: Performance isn't the core of my question, my question pertains to the exact operations of the method, something which I DID attempt to research.  Where exactly can I view how, say, Google Chrome implements this method?

Comment: I'd appreciate it if somebody who voted to close could explain why.  I'm really not being combative here, I genuinely want to know why there seems to be such a strong negative reaction to my question.  Both people voted that it is too broad, yet it seems to me to be quite specific, unless the answer is that it varies drastically from browser to browser.

Comment: Under which hood? If you want to see how Google V8 implements it, look at the source code. Or Mozilla's, look at theirs. This isn't a programming problem. It's a programmer's curiosity.

Comment: I did say this: *"And most browsers (except IE) are open source so you can peek at how they implement that."*. Then, again, a quick search returns these: [Blink](https://chromium.googlesource.com/) (Chrome, Opera), [Webkit](https://www.webkit.org/building/checkout.html) (Safari), [Gecko](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/)(Firefox)

Comment: Alright, fair enough.  I appreciate the help.  I did look around after you said that and didn't find those resources, but I suppose I just wasn't looking hard enough.

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer Those are [layout engines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_browser_engine) (which consume and render resources like HTML and CSS), not [JavaScript engines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_engine) (examples being [V8](https://developers.google.com/v8/) or [SpiderMonkey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey)). Wouldn't the implementation of `getElementsByClassName()` be in the browser's JS engine, not the layout engine?

Comment: @ajp15243 [Here's WebKit's repo, which so happens to contain DOM functions.](https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/blob/5b7f307f78ff665c0102bd008d2a47b9b2f8e5b5/Source/WebCore/dom/Document.cpp#L4405).

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer Good point, given that the DOM is indeed not a core JS concept, it stands to reason the layout engine would hook into the JS engine and define the DOM functions itself.

Comment: Look at all this valuable information in comments, not answers, because it was closed.